# I've waited more than 10 minutes and didn't see JUnit stoped or finished

Tags: junit

I am learning JUnit5, here is the code.

```
@Test
@Timeout(value = 1000, unit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
void testSquareRoot() {
    int actual_rs = calculator.squareRoot(4);
    assertEquals(2, actual_rs);
}
```

to test this method

```
public int squareRoot(int n) {
    for (; ;) ;
}
```

[image]

I've waited more than 10 minutes and didn't see JUnit stoped or finished.

it seems that Timeout in JUnit 5 does not work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am also facing the same problem now.